# go vet range variable captured by func literal when using go routine inside of for each loop

Tags: go

I'm not really sure what a 'func literal' is thus this error is confusing me a bit. I think I see the issue - I'm referencing a range value variable from inside a new go routine thus the value might change at anytime and not be what we expect. What's the best way to solve the issue?

The code in question:

```
func (l *Loader) StartAsynchronous() []LoaderProcess {
    for _, currentProcess := range l.processes {
        cmd := exec.Command(currentProcess.Command, currentProcess.Arguments...)
        log.LogMessage("Asynchronously executing LoaderProcess: %+v", currentProcess)
        go func() {
            output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
            if err != nil {
                log.LogMessage("LoaderProcess exited with error status: %+v\n %v", currentProcess, err.Error())
            } else {
                log.LogMessage("LoaderProcess exited successfully: %+v", currentProcess)
                currentProcess.Log.LogMessage(string(output))
            }
            time.Sleep(time.Second * TIME_BETWEEN_SUCCESSIVE_ITERATIONS)
        }()
    }
    return l.processes
}
```

My proposed fix:

```
func (l *Loader) StartAsynchronous() []LoaderProcess {
    for _, currentProcess := range l.processes {
        cmd := exec.Command(currentProcess.Command, currentProcess.Arguments...)
        log.LogMessage("Asynchronously executing LoaderProcess: %+v", currentProcess)
        localProcess := currentProcess
        go func() {
            output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
            if err != nil {
                log.LogMessage("LoaderProcess exited with error status: %+v\n %v", localProcess, err.Error())
            } else {
                log.LogMessage("LoaderProcess exited successfully: %+v", localProcess)
                localProcess.Log.LogMessage(string(output))
            }
            time.Sleep(time.Second * TIME_BETWEEN_SUCCESSIVE_ITERATIONS)
        }()
    }
    return l.processes
}
```

But does that really solve the problem? I've just moved the reference from the range variable to a different local variable whose value is based off of the iteration of the for each loop that I'm in.

Comment: An explanation of this problem is now in the official FAQ here: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Don't feel bad it's a common mistake for new comers in Go, and yes the var **currentProcess** changes for each loop, so your goroutines will use the last process in the slice *l.processes*, all you have to do is pass the variable as a parameter to the anonymous function, like this:

```
func (l *Loader) StartAsynchronous() []LoaderProcess {

    for ix := range l.processes {

        go func(currentProcess *LoaderProcess) {

            cmd := exec.Command(currentProcess.Command, currentProcess.Arguments...)
            log.LogMessage("Asynchronously executing LoaderProcess: %+v", currentProcess)

            output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
            if err != nil {
                log.LogMessage("LoaderProcess exited with error status: %+v\n %v", currentProcess, err.Error())
            } else {
                log.LogMessage("LoaderProcess exited successfully: %+v", currentProcess)
                currentProcess.Log.LogMessage(string(output))
            }

            time.Sleep(time.Second * TIME_BETWEEN_SUCCESSIVE_ITERATIONS)

        }(&l.processes[ix]) // passing the current process using index

    }

    return l.processes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated code that looks great! I had a gnarly bug in my code that took over an hour to fix related to something very similar. I was returning []*LoaderProcess before not realizing that a slice is already a pointer so I was essentially returning a slice of pointers where each pointer pointed to the same LoaderProcess instance which happened to be the last command to finish. Which was different every time after executing. So two big lessons learned from one piece of code. Thank you.

Comment: Do we have to send by using index?

Answer (score 65):

For those looking for a simpler example:

**This is wrong:**

```
func main() {
  for i:=0; i<10; i++{
    go func(){

        // Here i is a "free" variable, since it wasn't declared
        // as an explicit parameter of the func literal, 
        // so IT'S NOT copied by value as one may infer. Instead,
        // the "current" value of i
        // (in most cases the last value of the loop) is used
        // in all the go routines once they are executed.

        processValue(i)

    }()
  }
}

func processValue(i int){
  fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Is not exactly an error but could lead to unexpected behavior since the variable **i**, which controls your loop could be changed from other go routine. It's actually [go vet command](https://golang.org/cmd/vet/) which alerts about this. Go vet helps precisely to find this kind of suspicious constructs, it *uses heuristics that do not guarantee all reports are genuine problems, but it can find errors not caught by the compilers*. So it's a good practice to run it from time to time.

Go Playground runs **go vet** before running the code, you can see that in action [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Jr6P6XlRg50).

**This is correct:**

```
func main() {
  for i:=0; i<10; i++{
    go func(differentI int){

        processValue(differentI)

    }(i) // Here i is effectively passed by value since it was
         // declared as an explicit parameter of the func literal
         // and is taken as a different "differentI" for each
         // go routine, no matter when the go routine is executed
         // and independently of the current value of i.
  }
}

func processValue(i int){
  fmt.Println(i)
}
```

I intentionally named the func literal parameter *differentI* to make it obvious that it is a different variable. Doing it that way is safe for concurrent use, **go vet** won't complain and you'll get no weird behaviors. You can see that in action [here](https://play.golang.org/p/mKmp3kxD7QN). (You will see nothing since the printing is done on different go routines but the program will exit successfully)

And by the way, a **func literal** is basically an anonymous function :)

Comment: i sort of get why that initial example is wrong but intuitively, it doesn't fully sit right with me. in that case, isn't the variable i just an integer and not a pointer so realistically, it shouldn't be an error?

Comment: The go internals around this subject are pretty interesting, take a look at [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/go-internals-capturing-loop-variables-in-closures/). When you're not declaring explicit parameters inside the closure, the go compiler has to treat them like a pointer, so they end up working with the same value of `i`. It's worth understanding this stuff fully, thanks for your observation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome simplified example. After using GoLang for a few years now I've learned that passing your immediate variable through the `go func` parameter is the best way to work with anonymous multi-threaded go functions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, what you did is the simplest way of fixing this warning properly.

Before the fix, there was only a *single* variable, and all goroutines were referring to it. This means they did not see the value from when they started but the current value. In most cases this is the last one from the range.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Can you confirm that func literal is just a function defined in-line? Such as required by an in-line go routine?